# What does osmdroid's MapView.setMultiTouchControls() do?

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid

I was wondering what the `setMultiTouchControls()` function of the `MapView` is doing exactly. There is not explanation in the [Documentation](http://osmdroid.azurewebsites.net/osmdroid-android-5.0.1-javadoc/index.html) and I couldn't notice any difference when using or not using it. F.e. the `RotationGestureOverlay`  and the pinch zooming is always working.

Comment: It looks like it enables/disables the multitouch controller, which has a large part in pinching. Great question though!

Comment: @spy that's what I thought. But pinching is still working without the multitouch controller :-/